# Adding and removing style attribute from div with jquery

Tags: jquery, css, dhtml

I've inherited a project I'm working on and I'm updating some jquery animations (very little practice with jquery).

I have a div I need to add and remove the style attribute from. Here is the div:

```
<div id='voltaic_holder'>
```

At one point in the animation I need to add a style to it:

```
<div id='voltaic_holder' style='position:absolute;top:-75px'>
```

I've searched around and found the `.removeAttr()` method but I can't see how to add it, or even remote parts of it (like the top:-75px only).

Thanks,

Comment: `$('voltaic_holder').style = null` perhaps? Styles have their own entire object tree. most other attributes are just key=value type data.

Answer (score 311, accepted):

You could do any of the following

Set each style property individually:

```
$("#voltaic_holder").css("position", "relative");
```

Set multiple style properties at once:

```
$("#voltaic_holder").css({"position":"relative", "top":"-75px"});
```

Remove a specific style:

```
$("#voltaic_holder").css({"top": ""});
// or
$("#voltaic_holder").css("top", "");
```

Remove the entire style attribute:

```
$("#voltaic_holder").removeAttr("style")
```

Comment: Can I add more than 1 css property per line? Or do I have to do one for each style property like so:

`$("#voltaic_holder").css("position", "relative");`
`$("#voltaic_holder").css("top", "-75");`

Comment: To answer that, yes you can. Just use an object literal on the .css() function. Like $('foo').css({'height':'30px','width':'50px'});

Comment: @AdamAlbrecht How can I remove specific style that I have added because in $("#voltaic_holder").removeAttr("style") it removes all applied style that was by default with newly added.

Answer (score 28):

To completely remove the style attribute of the `voltaic_holder` span, do this:

```
$("#voltaic_holder").removeAttr("style");
```

To add an attribute, do this:

```
$("#voltaic_holder").attr("attribute you want to add", "value you want to assign to attribute");
```

To remove only the top style, do this:

```
$("#voltaic_holder").css("top", "");
```

Answer (score 19):

If you are using jQuery, use [css](http://api.jquery.com/css/) to add CSS

```
$("#voltaic_holder").css({'position': 'absolute',
    'top': '-75px'});
```

To remove CSS attributes

```
$("#voltaic_holder").css({'position': '',
    'top': ''});
```

Comment: You cannot remove the position or top attribute from the voltaic_holder element, because it does not have thos attributes. Those are css properties defined in the style attribute.

Comment: @Peter - doh!  Edited to use `.css`

Answer (score 12):

The easy way to handle this (and best HTML solution to boot) is to set up classes that have the styles you want to use.  Then it's a simple matter of using [addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) and [removeClass()](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/), or even [toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/).

```
$('#voltaic_holder').addClass('shiny').removeClass('dull');
```

or even

```
$('#voltaic_holder').toggleClass('shiny dull');
```

Answer (score 7):

In case of **.css** method in jQuery for **!important** rule will not apply.

In this case we should use **.attr** function.

For Example:
If you want to add style as below:
`<div id='voltaic_holder' style='position:absolute;top:-75px !important'>`

You should use:
`$("#voltaic_holder").attr("style", "position:absolute;top:-75px !important");`

Hope it helps some one.

Answer (score 4):

Remove style attribute from div using J query:

```
$("#TableDiv").removeAttr("style");
```

Add style to div using J query:

```
$("#TableDiv").attr("style", "display: none;");
```

Add style using html:

```
<div class="row" id="TableDiv" style="display: none;">
</div>
```

Hope it will helpful :)

Answer (score 2):

Anwer is here
[How to dynamically add a style for text-align using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/883180/how-to-dynamically-add-a-style-for-text-align-using-jquery)